# echo $ANDROID_HOME returns blank in Mac

Tags: android, bash, macos

I set the ANDROID_HOME in .bash_profile and run source ~/.bash profile but after close and open the terminal back then run echo $ANDROID_HOME return blank

.bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Najibah/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platfrom-tools
```

[This happened when I run echo $ANDROID_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrh0G.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `source ~/.bash_profile` from the `.bash_profile` file, because it leads to a loop. You only need to run the command from the terminal in order to load an updated version of the file. New terminal windows will use the latest version of the file anyway.

After changing the `.bash_profile`, run `source ~/.bash_profile` from your terminal window, and then run `echo $ANDROID_HOME`. You should get the expected value.

Comment: my bash_profile only contains this line: export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/artanberisha/Android/sdk , any idea what to do ? since I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Directory should be wrapped in double quotes.

Change `JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home`
like this `JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home"`

Answer (score -1):

I stack with it too. .bashrc editing not claim success. Answer is here: https://askubuntu.com/a/60221/965574 you need to add strings to the .profile file

Comment: Whilst we all love links to external sources, the links can become invalid for numerous reason. Please include all the required information in your answer.